# Assign select statement to variable and reuse in other query asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on big query in that i'm reusing same select statement for 4 times so here, I'd like to set some slow query results to a variable, 'var_sql', so I can use them again in other queries.

for eg:

```
string var_sql = "select Session_Id from sessions where UserId='" 
                 + Session["userid"].ToString() + "'";

SqlCommand command 
= new SqlCommand("Select distinct right(start_time,7) as st_time,   right(end_time,7) as ed_time from Session_Info where CourseName = '" 
+ coursename.SelectedValue 
+ "' and Session_Id not in (select Session_Id from sessions where   UserId='" 
+ Session["userid"].ToString() + "') and start_time not in (select start_time from   Session_Info where Convert(varchar,start_time, 108) between (select right(start_time,7) from   Session_Info where Session_Id in (var_sql )) and  (select right(dateadd(minute,-1,end_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (var_sql ))) and end_time not in (select end_time from Session_Info where Convert(varchar,end_time, 108) between (select right(dateadd(minute,+1,start_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in   (var_sql )) and  (select right(end_time,7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (var_sql ))) ", 
connection);
```

see am using same var_sql in four places.. here i have tried like this but it s not working fine.. can anyone help me on it?

Comment: In one way is it not working fine?

Comment: Please state what is the problem. "It's not working fine" won't tell us what you expect/how you want the code to work. Provide part of code where you suspect something is wrong.

Comment: in the second query instead of (@select_ID). i want to use the assigned variable(var_sql) there.

Comment: am getting an error like Invalid column name 'var_sql'.

Answer (score 1):

**You shall not use string concatenation to create a queries** because it is prone to SQL injections ([see explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)). Also take a look at [this](http://xkcd.com/327/) so you won't forget it next time. Fun things stuck in mind better than anything.

Fun aside, you should re-design your query completely and use `SqlParameter` to form a command. See a how to use parameters [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
    //...do your stuff with command
}
```

As you have not described requirements, it is impossible to give an advice how to re-design query, but you should try to join `Session_Id` table to itself.

**EDIT:**

**This definitely is not the correct right way to do it (see my previous comments why)**, but it seems that you do not want to re-design anything. As I already said in comments, you need to use `var_sql` **outside** of double quotes ("") so content of `var_sql` is added to the query, not the name of the variable itself.

Here goes nothing:

```
string var_sql = "select Session_Id from sessions where UserId='" 
                 + Session["userid"].ToString() + "'";
SqlCommand command 
= new SqlCommand("Select distinct right(start_time,7) as st_time,   right(end_time,7) as ed_time from Session_Info where CourseName = '" 
+ coursename.SelectedValue 
+ "' and Session_Id not in (select Session_Id from sessions where   UserId='" 
+ Session["userid"].ToString() + "') and start_time not in (select start_time from   Session_Info where Convert(varchar,start_time, 108) between (select right(start_time,7) from   Session_Info where Session_Id in (" + var_sql + " )) and  (select right(dateadd(minute,-1,end_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (" + var_sql + " ))) and end_time not in (select end_time from Session_Info where Convert(varchar,end_time, 108) between (select right(dateadd(minute,+1,start_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in   (" + var_sql + " )) and  (select right(end_time,7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (" + var_sql + " ))) ", 
connection);
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion but this is not the question asked.

Comment: Query is designed poorly that is where the problem comes from. I recommend to redesign query itself and use `SqlParameters` as well

Comment: your edited answer is way to good compare to your 1st posted answer that I commented on. Anyway comments are meant to improve answer here in SO. :)

Comment: yes i need to join the session_id table.. but what ever i try it displaying error like Invalid column name 'var_sql'.

Comment: This means that you have put `var_sql` inside the quotes and SQL server tries to parse it. You should put it outside of quotes so that you get correct SQL command. Aside from what I said in my answer, I would recommend you to check what value is contained in `command.Command` in Debug mode.

Comment: Is it possible to assign a select statement to a string variable?

Comment: Of course you can assign query to string variable and pass it in `SqlCommand` constructor as a parameter. But this is not your main concern. At first you should re-design and simplify your query. We can't help with it as you have not shared any details about requirements.

Comment: I have edited my query again.. if u go through again means surely u can give any idea for this issue. Thanks

Comment: I have updated answer, but once again - it might work, but this is not a right way to do it!

Comment: Your right sir.. i have to redesign my query. i have tried ur query but am getting error like Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

My big thanks for all the replies. Especially kaspars Ozols.
As u said i have redesign my query and used stored procedure like this.

create procedure b_timing

(

```
@UserId nvarchar(70),
@CourseName varchar(max)
)
as
begin
declare @select_ID varchar(50)    
select @select_ID =  Session_Id from sessions where UserId=@UserId
Select distinct right(start_time,7) as st_time, right(end_time,7) as ed_time from      Session_Info where CourseName = @CourseName and Session_Id not in (@select_ID) and start_time not in (select start_time from Session_Info where Convert(varchar,start_time, 108) between (select right(start_time,7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (@select_ID)) and  (select right(dateadd(minute,-1,end_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (@select_ID))) and end_time not in (select end_time from Session_Info where Convert(varchar,end_time, 108) between (select right(dateadd(minute,+1,start_time),7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (@select_ID)) and  (select right(end_time,7) from Session_Info where Session_Id in (@select_ID)))
end
```

and called it in asp.net c# like this

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    connection.Open();
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("b_timing", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session["userid"].ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", coursename.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    da.SelectCommand = command;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.Columns.Add("timing", typeof(string), "st_time+' '+'To'+' '+ed_time");

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        timing.DataSource = dt;
        timing.DataTextField = "timing";
        timing.DataValueField = "timing";
        timing.DataBind();
        timing.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose Batch Timing", "0"));
        timing.Visible = true;
        timing.Focus();
    }
```

It is working fine now